# "Validation Error" when trying to run `terraform apply`

Tags: terraform, newrelic

I have the following resources that I'm trying to create:

```
resource "newrelic_alert_policy" "rpm_production_alert_policy" {
  name = "RPM (Production) Alert Policy (Terraform)"
  incident_preference = "PER_CONDITION"
}

resource "newrelic_alert_channel" "rpm_production_slack" {
  name                          = "RPM Production Slack (Terraform)"
  type                          = "slack"
  config {
    channel                     = "rpm-terrarelic"
    url                         = "URLGOESHERE (obfuscated)"
  }
}

resource "newrelic_alert_policy_channel" "rpm_production_alert_policy_slack" {
  policy_id                     = newrelic_alert_policy.rpm_production_alert_policy.id
  channel_ids                   = [
                                    newrelic_alert_channel.rpm_production_slack.id
                                  ]
}

resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "median_duration" {
  policy_id                     = newrelic_alert_policy.rpm_production_alert_policy.id
  name                          = "median_duration"
  description                   = "Alert when transactions are taking too long (this is a test description)"
  nrql {
    query                       = "SELECT median(duration) from Transaction where team = 'rpm' facet name since 1 month ago limit 500"
    evaluation_offset           = 3
  }
  critical {
    operator                    = "above"
    threshold                   = 2
    threshold_duration          = 60
    threshold_occurrences       = "AT_LEAST_ONCE"
  }
  violation_time_limit_seconds  = 3600
  value_function                = "single_value"
}
```

When I comment out the `newrelic_nrql_alert_condition` resource and run `terraform apply` with my New Relic API key and `-var-file` flag, the resources are successfully created.  But when I un-comment the `newrelic_nrql_alert_condition` resource and re-run the command, I get the following error:

```
newrelic_nrql_alert_condition.median_duration: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Validation Error
│ 
│   with newrelic_nrql_alert_condition.median_duration,
│   on foobar.tf line 22, in resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "median_duration":
│   22: resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "median_duration" {
│ 
╵
```

The `{` in the last line (`22: resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "median_duration" {`) was underlined, implying that this is where the validation error lies, but I don't see any deviation between this resource statement and an identical one with different values for certain keywords such as `nrql.query`, therefore the error message doesn't appear to be terribly helpful on its face.

I tried different values for the `name` param of the resource, thinking there might be a uniqueness constraint on alert conditions in New Relic, but that didn't work.

I tried moving the problematic resource block to the top of the file, in case the error was a red herring for a syntax problem earlier in the file, but I then saw the same error message but with a reference to line 1 instead of line 22.  This tells me the problem really is with this resource block, and the error is not a red herring.

I Googled around for docs which would explain the different types of validation errors, but I wasn't able to find any.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:

When I run `terraform validate` for this module, I get the message `Success! The configuration is valid.`.

Comment: Does the same error occur when you execute the `plan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While researching current and closed issues in the [New Relic Terraform Provider GitHub page](https://github.com/newrelic/terraform-provider-newrelic), I found that the `TF_LOG` flag can be passed for more granular logging.  After passing this flag and discovering that the logging details at version 2.21.0 were insufficient, I discovered that version 2.29.0 of the gem has more granular log details.  I upgraded and passed the flag again, and discovered that the NRQL queries passed to an alert condition must not contain `LIMIT` clauses.  I removed the one I had included, and re-ran `terraform apply`, and it worked fine.